# How to obtain a hash code of an SVN repository?

Tags: svn, hash

I would like to have a hash code for a specific revision of an SVN repository. The goal is to have a way to verify that a given set of files is a legitimate working copy of that repository (has not been modified). A preferred solution would be some built-in command of svn.

Comment: I don't think SVN has that as a builtin, and I don't think it's feasible to ask the server to compute it, because it involves going through contents through every file in this revision.

The pragmatic option would be to do a separate checkout, calculate the hash of contents on that copy, and then compare to your repo.

Comment: Like written by @BartekBanachewicz I do not think there is a built in solution available, but another possibility might be to calculate a hash for each file on check in and store it as property. Then you can calculate the hash for a given file and check whether it matches with the one from the repository. The calculation on the check in (or after the check in) might be possible with a hook script